# View Default value for User Defined Table Type columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-table-type

I have a user defined table type in SQL Server 2014 that I need to drop and recreate. However, if I use the script from SSMS, the default value constraints that are on some of the columns, will not be created.

I also have problems viewing the default constraint, so I do not what the default value should be.

Is there a way to view what those default value constraints contain?

```
CREATE TYPE [Logging].[LogElements] AS TABLE(
[LogMessage] [nvarchar](MAX) NOT NULL,
[MessageTypeId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[Origin] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[JobRunId] [int] NULL,
[InvoiceId] [int] NULL,
[AccountlineId] [int] NULL,
[MSErrorCode] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[LogStatusId] [int] NOT NULL,
[LogUser] [varchar](50) NULL
```

)
GO

Above is the definition as it is created when generating script in SSMS. As you can see, the default values are not in the script.

Comment: Please share the type definition in your question.

Comment: @RandolphWest Added now. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Strange, it seems to work when I test that on a 2014 (12.0.4439.1 to be precise).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find your user-defined table type:

```
-- UDTT will have a 'TT prefix'
select * from sys.objects where type = 'TT' and name like '%LogElements%';
```

In my output, the object was called `TT_LogElements_3A4CA8FD` and had an `object_id` of `978102525`.

Now we can use a script similar to Ryan Cooper's answer, by plugging that `object_id` into the `WHERE` clause, as the `parent_object_id`:

```
SELECT o.name AS [Constraint Name],
    cl.name AS [Column Name],
    s.name AS [Data Type],
    cl.max_length AS [Length],
    c.text AS [Default Value]
FROM sys.syscomments c
INNER JOIN sys.objects o
    ON c.id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns cl
    ON o.parent_object_id = cl.object_id
        AND cl.default_object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.systypes s
    ON cl.system_type_id = s.xtype
WHERE o.type = 'D'
    AND parent_object_id = 978102525;
```

This is my example output, which is fairly trivial to convert into a T-SQL script for recreating them.

```
[Constraint Name]               [Column Name]   [Data Type] [Length] [Default Value]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DF__TT_LogEle__LogSt__3B40CD36  LogStatusId     int         4        ((0))
DF__TT_LogEle__LogUs__3C34F16F  LogUser         varchar     50       ('Test')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see the defaults and their definitions with this query:

```
select object_name(o.parent_object_id) as ObjectName
        , cl.name as ColumnName
        , o.name as DefaultName
        , c.text as DefaultDefintion
from sys.syscomments c
join sys.objects o on c.id = o.object_id
join sys.columns cl on cl.object_id = o.parent_object_id AND cl.default_object_id = o.object_id 
where o.type = 'D'
```

Edited to find user defined types:

```
    DECLARE @MyTable AS dbo.MyTableType; 

select object_name(o.parent_object_id) as ObjectName 
             , cl.name as ColumnName 
             , o.name as DefaultName 
             , c.text as DefaultDefintion
from tempdb.sys.syscomments c 
join tempdb.sys.objects o on c.id = o.object_id 
join tempdb.sys.columns cl on cl.object_id = o.parent_object_id AND cl.default_object_id = o.object_id 
where o.type = 'D'
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not seem to also show for user-defined-table-types. I cannot see the defaults from my user defined table type.

Comment: This is pretty hacky, but works in my test.

Comment: DECLARE @MyTable AS dbo.MyTableTable;

select object_name(o.parent_object_id) as ObjectName
  , cl.name as ColumnName
  , o.name as DefaultName
  , c.text as DefaultDefintion
  , o.*
from tempdb.sys.syscomments c
join tempdb.sys.objects o on c.id = o.object_id
join tempdb.sys.columns cl on cl.object_id = o.parent_object_id AND cl.default_object_id = o.object_id 
where o.type = 'D'

Comment: Thanks again, Ryan. Marked Randolphs post as answer since it was a bit more easy to read (the results), but yours helped along.